# return HttpPostedFile in service with async Task

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have async Task method like these:

```
 public async Task<Slider> EditSlider(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

            if (file != null)
            {
                var pic = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/slider"), pic);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
            return file;
    }
```

but in `return file` line I get

> Cannot convert expression HttpPostedFileBase to async method return type

How can I return it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to return that type, you need to declare your method as returning that type.

Comment: like these? `public async Task<HttpPostedFileBase> EditSlider(HttpPostedFileBase file)` @SLaks

Comment: All your method is doing is saving a file passed to it. It should be just `public void EditSlider(HttpPostedFileBase file) { .. }` and remove the `return file;` line.

Comment: I do it but now in controller I get "Cannot convert source type 'void' to target type string" into `slider.Image = _sliderService.EditSlider(file);` @StephenMuecke

Comment: That has nothing to do with the code you have shown. And what is it your trying to do anyway. You cannot convert `HttpPostedFileBase` to `string`. Best guess is you want to set the value of `Image` to the path that the file was saved to - in which case ask a new question with the relevant details (your method would need to be `private string EditSlider(HttpPostedFileBase file) { .. return path; }`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `file` is `HttpPostedFileBase`, not a `Slider`. So if anything, it would be `Task<HttpPostedFileBase>`.

However, nothing about your code is async, so you'd just return `HttpPostedFileBase` instead of `Task<HttpPostedFileBase>`.

```
public HttpPostedFileBase EditSlider(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        var pic = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/slider"), pic);
        file.SaveAs(path);
    }
    return file;
}
```

Your method also has a misleading name - nothing here is being edited.. it's simply saving an uploaded file.. but that's for another time

Comment: Exactly. No need for this method to be `async`.

Comment: Thanks! but now one more question, I equal it with a variable image in my controller like these: `var getphoto = _sliderService.Edit(file);` and 
               `slider.Image = getphoto;` but I get error "Cannot convert source type HttpPostedFileBase to target type string" any idea?

Comment: The method can be just `void` (it just returning the same object passd to it)

Comment: @EdgarG That depends on what `slider.Image` is expecting as a string. If it's the path of the file you saved, you'd need to change your method to return the path, rather than the file.

Comment: what kind of object I need to return if in controller I equal to object in my database?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your method signature to be

```
public async Task<HttpPostedFileBase> EditSlider(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
       //your code here
    }
```

To call,

```
var data = await EditSlider(myfile);
```

Comment: Thanks! but now one more question, I equal it with a variable image in my controller like these: `var getphoto = _sliderService.Edit(file);` and 
               `slider.Image = getphoto;` but I get error "Cannot convert source type HttpPostedFileBase to target type string" any idea?

Comment: @EdgarG, My bad ... Image is expecting string whereas your method returns a file. You should return proper data accordingly from your method.